Timeout connecting to remote PostgreSQL server
I am doing this task as self-education, to better understand the interaction between the client and the server.
So I have a laptop and a desktop computer at home. I will use the laptop as a client, and the desktop computer as a server. Both are connected to the network via a network cable.
Now about the client.
On the laptop, I wrote a small program in Python and sqlalchemy that takes data from the database and prints it out
connect_to_db_in_another_comp.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Base

url = URL.create(
    database="Test-connect-2",
    username="postgres",
    host="192.168.XXX.XX",
    password="123",
    port=5432,
    drivername="postgresql",
)

engine = create_engine(url)
connection = engine.connect() # traceback start here

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

all_records = session.query(User).all()
for i in all_records:
    print(i.user_name)

Full text traceback:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
connection to server at "192.168.XXX.XX", port 5432 failed: Connection
timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on that host and
accepting TCP/IP connections ?

Now about the server.
On the desktop computer in pgAdmin 4 in the already existing PostgreSQL 16 server I created the Test-connect-2 database. In this database I added one table "user". The server properties are as follows:
Host name/address: 192.168.XXX.XX
Port: 5432
Maintenance database: postgres
Username: postgres
In file pg_hba.conf I added last line:
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
I disabled the firewall and disabled the antivirus in both devices, but I still get the error I indicated above. Tell me what my mistake is

Maybe I'm entering the IP address incorrectly? In my desktop computer in cmd console I wrote 'ipconfig' and got IP-address. Is it true ?

Configure postgresql to log connections. That way you can see if the attempts reach it. Then install postgresql client packages on the laptop and also try psql.

To your question text add as text update: 1) OS and version. 2) How Postgres was installed? 3) Are you running Postgres in container/virtual environment?

Modify postgresql.conf to Allow Remote Connections
PostgreSQL, by default, only listens on localhost. To enable remote connections, add the following to
C:\NetIQ\idm\postgres\data\postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'
If the server has multiple interfaces, you can specify one.
Update pg_hba.conf for Remote Authentication
To allow remote connections, add the following to C:\NetIQ\idm\postgres\data\pg_hba.conf
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

For IPv6:
host all all ::0/0 md5

Test and Restart
Restart PostgreSQL and ensure firewall rules allow TCP connections on port 5432.
Additionally, make sure that if you're using a protected server, it allows TCP connections on port 5432. You can achieve this by modifying the firewall rules.
sudo ufw status

sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp

sudo ufw reload


Yes, I made these changes to the files in question.
As for the firewall: I temporarily disabled it on two computers. So it shouldn't be a problem
